# How to setup a self hosted WCF service

Tags: c#, .net, web-services, wcf

I have been through WCF concepts, read many and created SELF HOSTED service.

I added library to solution "CommunicationLibrary" which contains:

```
[ServiceContract]
interface ICommunication
{
    [OperationContract]
    string message();
}
```

and

```
public class Communication: ICommunication 
    {
        public string message()
        {
            return "WCF Method Accessed";
        }
    }
```

then I added console project to host it "WCFCommunicationHosting" which contains

```
class WcfHost
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Uri baseadd = "sasas";
          ServiceHost sh = new ServiceHost(typeof(CommunicationLibrary.Communication), baseadd);
          ServiceMetadataBehavior smb = new ServiceMetadataBehavior();
          smb.HttpGetEnabled = true;
          smb.MetadataExporter.PolicyVersion = PolicyVersion.Policy15;
          sh.Description.Behaviors.Add(smb);
          sh.Open();
          Console.WriteLine("Host Running");
        }
    }
```

now I don't understand that what to pass in `baseAdd`? I saw many examples like [this CodeProject article](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/622260/WCF-Self-Hosting-with-Example?fid=1837088&df=90&mpp=50&sort=Position&spc=Relaxed&tid=4667714) but I don't understand that why and how they are passing `localhost://`.

Comment: In your example your host will run and quit immediately. Add Console.ReadLine() after WriteLine(). You use localhost because it's...name of computer which hosts your service...

Comment: sorry i don't understand completely, please describe

Comment: what should i put in baseadd ?

Comment: Address of computer that will host your service. Probably same computer where you're running your program so `localhost` is fine. Or simply...omit that parameter: `new ServiceHost(typeof(CommunicationLibrary.Communication));`

Comment: i omitted that but throws error: UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: 'Communication Library.Communication.cs has zero application'

Comment: Contract is on ICommunication...

Answer (score 0):

Here is a working example. Its in vb.net, but you should get the idea of how/what is implemented.

Your service address is the address that you will specify in the connection / binding properties on your client that will consume the service. This is the address where it will find and communicate with your web service.

```
            Dim LocalIpAddress as string = "your pc ip"
            Dim tcp_port as string = "the port you want to use"

            Dim myServiceAddress As New Uri("http://" & localIpAddress & ":" & tcp_port & "/" & servicename)

            myservicehost = New ServiceHost(GetType(yourwcfservicemethodsclass), myServiceAddress)


            Dim BasicBinding As New BasicHttpBinding
            BasicBinding.MaxReceivedMessageSize = 2147483647

            myservicehost.AddServiceEndpoint(GetType(Iyourwcfservicemethodsclass), BasicBinding, myServiceAddress)


            ' Enable metadata publishing.
            Dim smb As New ServiceMetadataBehavior()
            smb.HttpGetEnabled = True
            smb.MetadataExporter.PolicyVersion = PolicyVersion.Policy15
            myservicehost.Description.Behaviors.Add(smb)

            myservicehost.Open()
```